# Problema con el uso de count en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos denomidada **registers**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
  id_plague    |       id_production   |   quadrant
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          3            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          3            |     2
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          3            |     3
--------------------------------------------------------------
     3         |          3            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          4            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          4            |     2
--------------------------------------------------------------
     3         |          4            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          5            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

La tabla registra las plagas que se encontraron en un cultivo **X** , el cultivo se divide en camas y cada cama se divide en cuadros. En este caso la cama es el **id_production** y los cuadros son el campo **quadrant** .

En la tabla se registra que plaga se encontró en cada cuadro de la cama.

Lo que necesito es contar el número de cuadros que se hayan registrado en el cultivo, hasta ahí bien porque puedo hacer una consulta simple como esta:

```
SELECT COUNT(quadrant) AS total
FROM registers;
```

y me da el siguiente resultado

```
--------------
    total
--------------
     8
--------------
```

El problema es que en un cuadro se pueden registrar varias plagas, entonces se guardar un registro por plaga por cuadro.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
  id_plague    |       id_production   |   quadrant
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          3            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          3            |     2
--------------------------------------------------------------
     4         |          3            |     3
--------------------------------------------------------------
     3         |          3            |     1
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

En esta tabla específicamente con estos registros se puede ver que:

- Que en el cuadro con valor 1 hay dos plagas con valor 4 y 3
- En los cuadros con valor 2 y 3 tienen una plaga con valor 4

Al hacer COUNT a estos registros específicamente me va dar 4 y lo que quiero es que sin importar cuantas plagas tenga un sólo cuadro me lo cuente una sola vez, es decir, que en este caso al hacer COUNT quiero que me de 3 porque encontro plagas en los cuadros 1, 2 y  3

Sólo me interesa saber que cuantos cuadros están infectados. Espero me pueda hacer entender con esta pregunta jejejeje

Comment: Si lo que quieres es hacer un conteo general, creo que lo solucionas haciendo un `SELECT SUM(quadrant) FROM...`

Comment: Recuerda que `COUNT` te indica el total de registros, pero `COUNT` suma los registros

Comment: gracias por tu comentario @IvanBotero pero no puedo sumarlos porque el quadrant son divisiones de la cama y son únicas, cada cama tiene el mismo número de divisiones, lo que me interesa saber es cuantos cuadros en total hay registrados pero si hay dos plagas en el mismo cuadrante que no me cuente dos cuadros sino uno sólo porque es el mismo cuadro, aunque creo que el SUM puede funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que esto es lo que quieress.

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM (SELECT quadrant
          FROM registers
          GROUP BY quadrant,id_production) RESULTADO;
```

el ejemplo [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad2244/22)

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas es esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT quadrant) FROM register
```

Básicamente: contar los `quadrant` distintos en `register`

Comment: creo que la respuesta es correcta pero es mas optimo `select count(*)
from (select COUNT(quadrant) FROM registers group by quadrant) resultado;` aqui puedes ver el resultado http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad2244/32 puede ser muy lento cuando la tabla crezca mas!, por otro lado excelente interpretacion de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Con esto te vale?:

```
SELECT COUNT(quadrant) AS total
FROM registers
GROUP BY id_production;
```

Intento agrupar por "producciones" que son los "identificadores" que quieres distinguir no?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no me funciona agruparlo por cama, lo que pasa es que como puede haber varias plagas en un mismo cuadro en la tabla se guarda una plaga por cuadro, entonces me cuenta nuevamente el mismo cuadro varias veces por el numero de plagas que tenga ese mismo cuadro, a mi interesa saber que ese cuadro tiene un registro y ya, espero me pueda entender jejeje

Comment: Voy a serte sincero, no me he enterado de nada .. jjaaj

Comment: dejame edito la pregunta mejor, creo que no me he podido explicar bien @DanielDíaz

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente necesitas contar los cuadrantes que tienes plaga, eso es equivalente a contar los **distintos** cuadrantes registrados

```
select count(distinct quadrant) from registers;
```

Si quisieras saber cuantos registros tienes por plaga seria:

```
select count(quadrant) from registers group by quadrant;
```

Siempre es recomendable hacer *count(_uncampo_)* no hacer *count(*)* porque consume mas recursos.